# TimelinePlot, RotateLabel

Tags: plotting, date-and-time

Where am I going wrong with the following syntax?

```
TimelinePlot[
    {Labeled[DateInterval[{{2020, 9, 1}, Today}],
    "Blah", Bottom, RotateLabel -> True]},
PlotLayout -> "Vertical"]
```

If `TimelinePlot` and `RotateLabel` are incompatible, is there a neat workaround?

Comment: Does `Rotate["Blah", -Pi/2]` instead of `"Blah"` solve your problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Manipulate[
 Labeled[ (*has three parts: expr, lbl, pos *)
  TimelinePlot[
   DateInterval[{{2020, 9, 1}, Today}]
   , PlotLayout -> "Vertical"
   , ImageSize -> Small
   , DateTicksFormat -> {
     "MonthNameShort"
     , " "
     , "YearShort"
     }
   ] (*expr*)
  , Framed[
   Rotate["Blah", ang]
   , Background -> LightBlue
   ] (*lbl*)
  , pos (*pos*)
  ]
 , {{pos, Right, "Position"}, {Right, Left, Top, Bottom}}
 , {{ang, 0, "Rotation"}, {0, \[Pi]/2, \[Pi], -\[Pi]/2}}
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, use the option `PlotLegends`

```
TimelinePlot[{DateInterval[{{2020, 9, 1}, Today}]},
 PlotLayout -> "Vertical",
 ImageSize -> Small,
 PlotLegends -> Placed["Blah", Below]]
```

[image]